# Update PHP variable when a checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have an HTML form with checkboxes, and each one has a label.

Every checkbox represents a space for a room, so if a user checks one, it should decrease by one.

My JavaScript is working fine, it's the backend I'm struggling with.

I'm not sure how to store the available spaces in php to make other users see the updated value. It doesn't need to be live, so I don't want to use Ajax. It's enough to update the values just after refreshing the page.

For example, there are currently 40 spaces available for a room. A user checks the checkbox for that room, and the space decreases to 39. Now, it should update the variables in the php code, and that's where my problem is.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Piarista Kollégium - Stúdiumi jelentkezés</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="main.css" />

</head>
<body>

<div class="topnav">

<div class="topnav-centered">
  <a href="#home" class="active">Jelentkezés</a>
</div>

<a href="updates.html">Frissítések</a>

<div class="topnav-right">
  <a href="login.html">Bejelentkezés</a>
</div>
</div>
<div id="head">
    <img src="logo.png">
</div>
<h2>Üdvözöllek, XY!</h2>
</div>


<form class="asd" id="checkbox" action="index.php"  method="post">
    <table>
      <thead>
          <tr>
            <th></th>
              <th>1.</th>
              <th>2.</th>
              <th>3.</th>
              <th>4.</th>
              <th>5.</th>
              <th>6.</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th>Hétfő</th>
                <td><input type="checkbox" id="he1" onclick="checkingFunction(this)" name="hetfo"><label id="he1" for="he1">40</label></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" id="he2" onclick="checkingFunction(this)" name="hetfo"><label id="he2" for="he2">40</label></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" id="he3" onclick="checkingFunction(this)" name="hetfo"><label id="he3" for="he3">40</label></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" id="he4" onclick="checkingFunction(this)" name="hetfo"><label id="he4" for="he4">40</label></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" id="he5" onclick="checkingFunction(this)" name="hetfo"><label id="he5" for="he5">40</label></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" id="he6" onclick="checkingFunction(this)" name="hetfo"><label id="he6" for="he6">40</label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>Kedd</th>
              <td><input type="checkbox" id="ke1" onclick="checkingFunction(this)" name="kedd"><label id="ke1" for="ke1">40</label></td>
              <td><input type="checkbox" id="ke2" onclick="checkingFunction(this)" name="kedd"><label id="ke2" for="ke2">40</label></td>
              <td><input type="checkbox" id="ke3" onclick="checkingFunction(this)" name="kedd"><label id="ke3" for="ke3">40</label></td>
              <td><input type="checkbox" id="ke4" onclick="checkingFunction(this)" name="kedd"><label id="ke4" for="ke4">40</label></td>
              <td><input type="checkbox" id="ke5" onclick="checkingFunction(this)" name="kedd"><label id="ke5" for="ke5">40</label></td>
              <td><input type="checkbox" id="ke6" onclick="checkingFunction(this)" name="kedd"><label id="ke6" for="ke6">40</label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>Szerda</th>
              <td><input type="checkbox" id="sze1" onclick="checkingFunction(this)" name="szerda"><label id="sze1" for="sze1">40</label></td>
              <td><input type="checkbox" id="sze2" onclick="checkingFunction(this)" name="szerda"><label id="sze2" for="sze2">40</label></td>
              <td><input type="checkbox" id="sze3" onclick="checkingFunction(this)" name="szerda"><label id="sze3" for="sze3">40</label></td>
              <td><input type="checkbox" id="sze4" onclick="checkingFunction(this)" name="szerda"><label id="sze4" for="sze4">40</label></td>
              <td><input type="checkbox" id="sze5" onclick="checkingFunction(this)" name="szerda"><label id="sze5" for="sze5">40</label></td>
              <td><input type="checkbox" id="sze6" onclick="checkingFunction(this)" name="szerda"><label id="sze6" for="sze6">40</label></td>
            <tr>
              <hr>
              <th>Csütörtök</th>
              <td><input type="checkbox" id="csu1" onclick="checkingFunction(this)" name="csutortok"><label id="csu1" for="csu1">40</label></td>
              <td><input type="checkbox" id="csu1" onclick="checkingFunction(this)" name="csutortok"><label id="csu2" for="csu2">40</label></td>
              <td><input type="checkbox" id="csu1" onclick="checkingFunction(this)" name="csutortok"><label id="csu3" for="csu3">40</label></td>
              <td><input type="checkbox" id="csu1" onclick="checkingFunction(this)" name="csutortok"><label id="csu4" for="csu4">40</label></td>
              <td><input type="checkbox" id="csu1" onclick="checkingFunction(this)" name="csutortok"><label id="csu5" for="csu5">40</label></td>
              <td><input type="checkbox" id="csu1" onclick="checkingFunction(this)" name="csutortok"><label id="csu6" for="csu6">40</label></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" class="button" value="Jelentkezés elküldése">
</form>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

var hetfoTomb = document.forms['checkbox'].elements[ 'hetfo' ];
var keddTomb = document.forms['checkbox'].elements[ 'kedd' ];
var szerdaTomb = document.forms['checkbox'].elements[ 'szerda' ];
var csutortokTomb = document.forms['checkbox'].elements[ 'csutortok' ];
var button = document.querySelector(".button");

var kotelezo = 2;
var hetfoC = 0;
var keddC = 0;
var szerdaC = 0;
var csutortokC = 0;

var h1hely = 40;
var h2hely = 40;
var h3hely = 40;
var h4hely = 40;
var h5hely = 40;
var h6hely = 40;

var k1hely = 40;
var k2hely = 40;
var k3hely = 40;
var k4hely = 40;
var k5hely = 40;
var k6hely = 40;

var sze1hely = 40;
var sze2hely = 40;
var sze3hely = 40;
var sze4hely = 40;
var sze5hely = 40;
var sze6hely = 40;

var csu1hely = 40;
var csu2hely = 40;
var csu3hely = 40;
var csu4hely = 40;
var csu5hely = 40;
var csu6hely = 40;

function checkingFunction(checkbox) {
  var change = checkbox.nextElementSibling;
  //HÉTFŐ
   if (change.id == "he1" || change.id == "he2" || change.id == "he3" || change.id == "he4" || change.id == "he5" || change.id == "he6") {
     enableIfItShould(hetfoC, hetfoTomb);
   } else if (change.id == "ke1" || change.id == "ke2" || change.id == "ke3" || change.id == "ke4" || change.id == "ke5" || change.id == "ke6") {
     enableIfItShould(keddC, keddTomb);
   } else if (change.id == "sze1" || change.id == "sze2" || change.id == "sze3" || change.id == "sze4" || change.id == "sze5" || change.id == "sze6") {
     enableIfItShould(szerdaC, szerdaTomb);
   } else if (change.id == "csu1" || change.id == "csu2" || change.id == "csu3" || change.id == "csu4" || change.id == "csu5" || change.id == "csu6") {
     enableIfItShould(csutortokC, csutortokTomb);
   }

  if (change.id == "he1") {
    if (checkbox.checked) {
      h1hely--;
      hetfoC++;
      disableIfFull(hetfoC, hetfoTomb);
    } else {
      h1hely++;
      hetfoC--;
    }
    change.innerHTML = h1hely;
  }
  else if (change.id == "he2") {
    if (checkbox.checked) {
      h2hely--;
      hetfoC++;
      disableIfFull(hetfoC, hetfoTomb);
    } else {
      h2hely++;
      hetfoC--;
    }
    change.innerHTML = h2hely;
  }
  else if (change.id == "he3") {
    if (checkbox.checked) {
      h3hely--;
      hetfoC++;
      disableIfFull(hetfoC, hetfoTomb);
    } else {
      h3hely++;
      hetfoC--;
    }
    change.innerHTML = h3hely;
  }
  else if (change.id == "he4") {
    if (checkbox.checked) {
      h4hely--;
      hetfoC++;
      disableIfFull(hetfoC, hetfoTomb);
    } else {
      h4hely++;
      hetfoC--;
    }
    change.innerHTML = h4hely;
  }
  else if (change.id == "he5") {
    if (checkbox.checked) {
      h5hely--;
      hetfoC++;
      disableIfFull(hetfoC, hetfoTomb);
    } else {
      h5hely++;
      hetfoC--;
    }
    change.innerHTML = h5hely;
  }
  else if (change.id == "he6") {
    if (checkbox.checked) {
      h6hely--;
      hetfoC++;
      disableIfFull(hetfoC, hetfoTomb);
    } else {
      h6hely++;
      hetfoC--;
    }
    change.innerHTML = h6hely;
  }
  //KEDD
  if (change.id == "ke1") {
    if (checkbox.checked) {
      k1hely--;
      keddC++;
      disableIfFull(keddC, keddTomb);
    } else {
      k1hely++;
      keddC--;
    }
    change.innerHTML = k1hely;
  }
  else if (change.id == "ke2") {
    if (checkbox.checked) {
      k2hely--;
      keddC++;
      disableIfFull(keddC, keddTomb);
    } else {
      k2hely++;
      keddC--;
    }
    change.innerHTML = k2hely;
  }
  else if (change.id == "ke3") {
    if (checkbox.checked) {
      k3hely--;
      keddC++;
      disableIfFull(keddC, keddTomb);
    } else {
      k3hely++;
      keddC--;
    }
    change.innerHTML = k3hely;
  }
  else if (change.id == "ke4") {
    if (checkbox.checked) {
      k4hely--;
      keddC++;
      disableIfFull(keddC, keddTomb);
    } else {
      k4hely++;
      keddC--;
    }
    change.innerHTML = k4hely;
  }
  else if (change.id == "ke5") {
    if (checkbox.checked) {
      k5hely--;
      keddC++;
      disableIfFull(keddC, keddTomb);
    } else {
      k5hely++;
      keddC--;
    }
    change.innerHTML = k5hely;
  }
  else if (change.id == "ke6") {
    if (checkbox.checked) {
      k6hely--;
      keddC++;
      disableIfFull(keddC, keddTomb);
    } else {
      k6hely++;
      keddC--;
    }
    change.innerHTML = k6hely;
  }
//SZERDA
  if (change.id == "sze1") {
    if (checkbox.checked) {
      sze1hely--;
      szerdaC++;
      disableIfFull(szerdaC, szerdaTomb);
    } else {
      sze1hely++;
      szerdaC--;
    }
    change.innerHTML = sze1hely;
  }
  else if (change.id == "sze2") {
    if (checkbox.checked) {
      sze2hely--;
      szerdaC++;
      disableIfFull(szerdaC, szerdaTomb);
    } else {
      sze2hely++;
      szerdaC--;
    }
    change.innerHTML = sze2hely;
  }
  else if (change.id == "sze3") {
    if (checkbox.checked) {
      sze3hely--;
      szerdaC++;
      disableIfFull(szerdaC, szerdaTomb);
    } else {
      sze3hely++;
      szerdaC--;
    }
    change.innerHTML = sze3hely;
  }
  else if (change.id == "sze4") {
    if (checkbox.checked) {
      sze4hely--;
      szerdaC++;
      disableIfFull(szerdaC, szerdaTomb);
    } else {
      sze4hely++;
      szerdaC--;
    }
    change.innerHTML = sze4hely;
  }
  else if (change.id == "sze5") {
    if (checkbox.checked) {
      sze5hely--;
      szerdaC++;
      disableIfFull(szerdaC, szerdaTomb);
    } else {
      sze5hely++;
      szerdaC--;
    }
    change.innerHTML = sze5hely;
  }
  else if (change.id == "sze6") {
    if (checkbox.checked) {
      sze6hely--;
      szerdaC++;
      disableIfFull(szerdaC, szerdaTomb);
    } else {
      sze6hely++;
      szerdaC--;
    }
    change.innerHTML = sze6hely;
  }

  if (change.id == "csu1") {
    if (checkbox.checked) {
      csu1hely--;
      csutortokC++;
      disableIfFull(csutortokC, csutortokTomb);
    } else {
      csu1hely++;
      csutortokC--;
    }
    change.innerHTML = csu1hely;
  }
  else if (change.id == "csu2") {
    if (checkbox.checked) {
      csu2hely--;
      csutortokC++;
      disableIfFull(csutortokC, csutortokTomb);
    } else {
      csu2hely++;
      csutortokC--;
    }
    change.innerHTML = csu2hely;
  }
  else if (change.id == "csu3") {
    if (checkbox.checked) {
      csu3hely--;
      csutortokC++;
      disableIfFull(csutortokC, csutortokTomb);
    } else {
      csu3hely++;
      csutortokC--;
    }
    change.innerHTML = csu3hely;
  }
  else if (change.id == "csu4") {
    if (checkbox.checked) {
      csu4hely--;
      csutortokC++;
      disableIfFull(csutortokC, csutortokTomb);
    } else {
      csu4hely++;
      csutortokC--;
    }
    change.innerHTML = csu4hely;
  }
  else if (change.id == "csu5") {
    if (checkbox.checked) {
      csu5hely--;
      csutortokC++;
      disableIfFull(csutortokC, csutortokTomb);
    } else {
      csu5hely++;
      csutortokC--;
    }
    change.innerHTML = csu5hely;
  }
  else if (change.id == "csu6") {
    if (checkbox.checked) {
      csu6hely--;
      csutortokC++;
      disableIfFull(csutortokC, csutortokTomb);
    } else {
      csu6hely++;
      csutortokC--;
    }
    change.innerHTML = csu6hely;
  }
}

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < hetfoTomb.length; i++) {
    if (hetfoTomb[i].checked) {
      hetfoC++;
    }
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < keddTomb.length; i++) {
    if (keddTomb[i].checked) {
      keddC++;
    }
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < szerdaTomb.length; i++) {
    if (szerdaTomb[i].checked) {
      szerdaC++;
    }
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < csutortokTomb.length; i++) {
    if (csutortokTomb[i].checked) {
      csutortokC++;
    }
  }
  // if (hetfoC >= kotelezo && keddC >= kotelezo && szerdaC >= kotelezo && csutortokC >= kotelezo) {
  //   alert("Tovább a véglegesítéshez!");
  // } else {
  //   alert("Hiba");
  // }
})

function disableIfFull(dayCounter, dayTomb) {
  if (dayCounter == kotelezo) {
    for (var i = 0; i<6; i++) {
      if (dayTomb[i].checked) {
        dayTomb[i].disabled = false;
      } else {
        dayTomb[i].disabled = true;
      }
    }
  }
}

function enableIfItShould(dayCounter, dayTomb) {
  if (dayCounter == kotelezo) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      if (dayTomb[i].disabled) {
        dayTomb[i].disabled = false;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I thought I could update the value in a script tag in the HTML after a checkbox is checked, but I don't really know how to do that.

I think my biggest problem is that I don't have specific names for the checkboxes. In a group there are 6 checkboxes with the same name.

Comment: Some idea of the database schema might be useful here. Also - the room bookings ~ do they reset at the end of each day or continue for 1week/1month etc etc...

Comment: They reset after every week.

Comment: you are using a database??

Comment: I can, but I have no idea how to use that at this project. Make a column for each days? And then make rows from 1 to 6?

Comment: a column for each room does not sound very efficient nor user friendly. A table of rooms, a table of staff/users that book rooms and a bookings table to store refences to the room/staff member with date and time - perhaps.

Comment: I explain you the background of this page. So, this is for a dormitory, where students have categories related to their grades, and there are around 80 students here. There is one studying room only in the building, which is not big enough for 80 students to study at the same time, so there are 6 times when the student can study at the room (The room can have 40 people in itself maximum). There are 6 times a day when you can study, and you can do it only on monday, tuesday, wednesday and thursday (4 days, each one with 6 time.) The students should check the right time when they want to study.